# how to hide parts of doxygen comments to doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

Suppose you have a rather complicated README you want Doxygen to process to produce the mainpage of the documentation, something along the lines of

```
/*! 
    \mainpage Welcome to this code

    \section S1 Introduction
    Some stuff to explain why you coded all this

    \section S2 Examples
    Many examples of how the code can be used
    !!! some line which you wouldn't write in a documentation

    \section S3 Some other stuff
*/
```

AND you want doxygen to ignore the line beginning with !!! BUT you don't want to erase the line because you plan on editing it later.

Well, how can you do that?

EDIT: The following:

```
/*! 
    \mainpage Welcome to this code

    \section S1 Introduction
    Some stuff to explain why you coded all this

    \section S2 Examples
    Many examples of how the code can be used
    \cond NEVER
    !!! some line which you wouldn't write in a documentation
    \endcond

    \section S3 Some other stuff
*/
```

fails to put section `S3` in the mainpage...

Comment: Did you have a look at \internal and \cond

Comment: I tried to `\cond NEVER !!! some line which you wouldn't write in a documentation \endcond` but it breaks the whole page so that `\section S3 Some other stuff` is not added. i'll check with `\internal`

Comment: I just now checked with `\internal !!! some line which you wouldn't write in a documentation \endinternal` and it works, so thank you  @albert . guess i'll make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
/*! 
    \mainpage Welcome to this code

    \section S1 Introduction
    Some stuff to explain why you coded all this

    \section S2 Examples
    Many examples of how the code can be used
    \internal
    !!! some line which you wouldn't write in a documentation
    \endinternal

    \section S3 Some other stuff
*/
```

achieves the desired goal, provided your doxyfile is set correctly ( INTERNAL_DOCS tag set to NO ). I aknowledge @albert for the tip.

Comment: A small addition. From the documentation: \cond starts a conditional section that ends with a corresponding \endcond command, which is typically found in another
comment block. For conditional sections within a comment block one should use a \if ... \endif block

Answer (score 3):

From the [HTML commands section](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html) in the manual:

> Finally, to put invisible comments inside comment blocks, HTML style comments can be used:
>
> ```
> /*! <!-- This is a comment with a comment block --> Visible text */
> ```

Comment: Notice that this simply hides the comments in the browser, while leaving them in the html source